# Is it possible to get all child entites without using @OneToMany annotation in one query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's assume that I have following entities:

- **UserEntities**:

```java
@Embeddable
@Data
public class ContactInformation implements Serializable {

    @Column()
    private String name;

    @Column()
    private String surname;

}

public class UserEntity {
    @Embedded
    private ContactInformation contactInformation;

    @Column()
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @Column()
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
}
```

- And **UserHobbyEntity**:

```java
public class UserHobbyEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = )
    @NotEmpty
    private String hobbyName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private UserEntity userEntity;
}
```

Now I want to get all users (using paginate) with his/her hobbies without using `@OneToMany` and map to new class called `SearchUserModel`:

```java
public class SearchUserModel {
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private List<String> hobbies;
    public SearchUserModel(String userId,
                           String name, String surname,
                           List<String> hobbies) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }
}
```

When I call the following repository method, spring boot says that **" Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection"**:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, String> {
    @Query("""
            SELECT new com.package.to.SearchUserModel(
              user.id,
              user.contactInformation.name,
              user.contactInformation.surname,
              (SELECT uh.hobbyName FROM UserHobbyEntity uh WHERE uh.userEntity.id = user.id)
            )
            FROM UserEntity user
            WHERE user.id != :userId
            """)
    Page<SearchUserModel> getUsersForUser(String userId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When i changed `List<String> hobbies` to `String hobby`, it works but I want to get all hobbies:

```java
public class SearchUserModel {
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    
    // this is working but i want to get all hobbies for each user
    public SearchUserModel(String userId,
                           String name, String surname,
                           String hobby) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use subqueries in select clause of jpql expression (see [this](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_select_clause)), this explains the error.

You have to declare one to many relation anyway if you wish to achieve this result, but you can mark it as lazy, so it will not be fetched unless explicitly requested.